# How do you name your Minecraft server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm creating a server for me and my friends at school so we can link and have fun together. I already created the server and everything, but they can't link if my server doesn't have a name!

How do I name it!?

Comment: I think you confuse `name` with `url`. The servers name is shown in the servers-list in minecraft(can even contain color/formatting), whereas the url is the address, your friends have to enter to find the server in the first place(see colorfusions answer).

Answer (score 6):

Your friends can use your IP address to connect to the server. You can get your external IP [just by searching for it on Google](http://google.com/search?q=what+is+my+external+ip).

If you want to actually have a proper name for your server with words instead of numbers, you'll need to register a domain name. This can be done through a registrar, but will cost money and is outside of the scope of this website.

Comment: There are free Dynamic DNS services which can serve as a domain service. This will be a subdomain of some kind (yourservernamehere.somefixedcompanyname.com), however.